# Python Simon Game: I Got Stuck Finishing the Sequence

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm finally finishing my Simon Game, but I have some doubts about how to complete the sequence.

Edit: As you asked I have edited my post. Here I will post my code as it was before this post. So here are my actual problems.

1) I don't know how to add one number to the sequence after each turn.

2) The first turn works fine, but I don't know how to start the next turn, I've tried to call again the function after checking the sequence but it doesn't worked.

The necessary code for the two things:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import random

base = Tkinter.Tk()

fr = Tkinter.Frame(base, bg='black', width='238', height='250')

score = Tkinter.Label(base, bg='black', fg='white', text='Score:')
score.place(x = 30, y = 15)

s = 0

scoreNum = Tkinter.Label(base, bg='black', fg='white', text = s)
scoreNum.place(x = 70, y = 15)

clicks = []
color = 0

def yellowClick():

    yellow.configure(activebackground='yellow3')
    yellow.after(500, lambda: yellow.configure(activebackground='yellow'))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 1
    clicks.append(color)

yellow = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                       width='7', height='5', activebackground='yellow',  
                       bg='yellow3', command = yellowClick)

yellow.place(x = 30, y = 50)

def blueClick():

    blue.configure(activebackground='medium blue')
    blue.after(500, lambda: blue.configure(activebackground='blue'))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 2
    clicks.append(color)

blue = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                     width='7', height='5', activebackground='blue',
                     bg='medium blue', command = blueClick)

blue.place(x = 125, y = 50)

def redClick():

    red.configure(activebackground='red3')
    red.after(500, lambda: red.configure(activebackground='red'))

    global clicks
    global color 

    color = 3
    clicks.append(color)

red = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                    width='7', height='5', activebackground='red',
                    bg = 'red3', command = redClick)    

red.place(x = 30, y = 145)

def greenClick():

    green.configure(activebackground='dark green')
    green.after(500, lambda: green.configure(activebackground='green4'))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 4
    clicks.append(color)

green = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                      width='7', height='5', activebackground='green4',
                      bg='dark green', command = greenClick)

green.place(x = 125, y = 145)   

def scoreUp():

    global s

    s = s + 1

    scoreNum.configure(text = s)


sequence = []

def checkSequence():

    global clicks
    global sequence

    if clicks == sequence:

        scoreUp()   

def showSequence():

    global sequence
    global clicks
    global check 

    r = random.randint(1, 4)

    if r == 1:

        yellow.configure(bg='yellow')
        yellow.after(1000, lambda: yellow.configure(bg='yellow3'))

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 2:

        blue.configure(bg='blue')
        blue.after(1000, lambda: blue.configure(bg='medium blue'))  

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 3:

        red.configure(bg='red')
        red.after(1000, lambda: red.configure(bg='red3'))   

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 4:

        green.configure(bg='green4')
        green.after(1000, lambda: green.configure(bg='dark green')) 

        sequence.append(r)      

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)


base.after(2000, showSequence)

fr.pack()

base.resizable(False, False)
base.mainloop()
```

The checkSequence function is activated by time because I could not find another way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by stop? Like halt and wait for an event?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: `sequence == sequence + 1` is equal to `0 == 1` and it is always False.

Comment: use `True/False` variables to control program - ie. `number_added = True`

Comment: `if turn_ended == True: number_added = False`

Comment: Ok, I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question already but you still had some problems, here is the full and complete code. I've made it more efficient and fixed the problems :)

This is working I've tested it. Just comment if there is anything you need to know

```
import Tkinter # you don't need to import Tkinter again, from ... import * moves all the functions from ... into your program
import random

base = Tkinter.Tk()

fr = Tkinter.Frame(base, bg='black', width='238', height='250')
fr.pack()

score = Tkinter.Label(base, bg='black', fg='white', text='Score:')
score.place(x = 30, y = 15)

scoreNum = Tkinter.Label(base, bg='black', fg='white', text = 0)
scoreNum.place(x = 70, y = 15)

global sequence
global clicks
global s
sequence = []
clicks = []
s = 0

yellow = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                       width='7', height='5', activebackground='yellow',  
                       bg='yellow3', command = lambda *args: Click(yellow, "yellow", "yellow3", 1))


blue = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                     width='7', height='5', activebackground='blue',
                     bg='medium blue', command = lambda *args: Click(blue, "blue", "medium blue", 2))

red = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                    width='7', height='5', activebackground='red',
                    bg = 'red3', command = lambda *args: Click(red, "red", "red3", 3))    

green = Tkinter.Button(base, bd='0', highlightthickness='0',
                      width='7', height='5', activebackground='green4',
                      bg='dark green', command = lambda *args: Click(green, "green", "dark green", 4))

yellow.place(x = 30, y = 50)
blue.place(x = 125, y = 50)
red.place(x = 30, y = 145)
green.place(x = 125, y = 145)   


def Click(button, colour1, colour2, number): # these arguments change so that you don't have to copy the function 10 times
    global clicks

    yellow.configure(activebackground=colour2)
    yellow.after(500, lambda: yellow.configure(activebackground=colour1))

    clicks.append(number)
    checkSequence() # why not do this straight away?

def checkSequence():
    global clicks
    global sequence
    global s

    print("clicks:    "+str(clicks)) # debug
    print("sequence:  "+str(sequence))

    if clicks != sequence[:len(clicks)]: # if all their clicks so far e.g. [1, 2, 4, 3] DONT fit with the sequence e.g. [3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
        print("           ...Incorrect!")
        s = 0
        scoreNum.configure(text = 0)
        sequence = []
        clicks = []
        base.after(1000, showSequence) # now move to the next value in the sequence

    elif clicks == sequence: # they have completed a sequence
        print("           ...Match!")
        s = s + 1
        scoreNum.configure(text = s)
        clicks = []
        base.after(1000, showSequence) # now move to the next value in the sequence

def showSequence():
    global sequence
    global clicks

    r = random.randint(1, 4)

    if r == 1:
        yellow.configure(bg='yellow')
        yellow.after(1000, lambda: yellow.configure(bg='yellow3'))

    elif r == 2:
        blue.configure(bg='blue')
        blue.after(1000, lambda: blue.configure(bg='medium blue'))  

    elif r == 3:
        red.configure(bg='red')
        red.after(1000, lambda: red.configure(bg='red3'))   

    elif r == 4:
        green.configure(bg='green')
        green.after(1000, lambda: green.configure(bg='dark green')) 

    sequence.append(r) # you don't need this in all the if statements, it always happens

base.after(100, showSequence)
base.resizable(False, False)
base.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I'm using python 3.4.1 so I changed all the tkinters to Tkinter

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Andrea does it work? If it does mark my answer correct!

Comment: Sorry, I was testing it, yes it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code based on furas' solution in the comments

```
def showSequence():

    global sequence    

    number_added = True
    r = random.randint(1, 4)

    if r == 1:
    elif r == 2:
    elif r == 3:
    elif r == 4:
    else:
        number_added = False

    return number_added # this will be True if a number was added, False if not
```

And to call the function:

```
number_added = showSequence()
if number_added:
    # stop sequence here
```

You also said you don't know how to stop it, try this:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

This will immediately stop the function you're currently in

Comment: Thank you, I wil try it.

Comment: No problem :) If there's anything else you need just add a comment

Comment: remember if this helped you I wouldn't mind a nice, big, green tick XD

Comment: Yes, it helped me.

Comment: But I don't know how to start the next turn right after the first turn ends. Any ideas?

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand better how to complete the sequence but I cannot fully test it until I add more turns, to see if it really remembers the sequence.

Comment: your sequence is a global variable, it will never forget it unless you reset it

Comment: What is the problem with your program? I've tested my code and it definitely works

Comment: Then the only thing that is not working now is, when I try to call the showSequence() function again for another turn, I tried to call it after the checking the sequence but nothing happens.

Comment: I'm sorry if my problems sound dumb, but is the first game I make in my life, and I don't have to much experience in programming.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code? And it's fine, everybody starts somewhere :)

Comment: I'll need to see the code with the problem so I can figure it out :)

Comment: Ok, give me a minute to fix the code and i'll add a new answer